# Error while running 'glxinfo' on a headless remote server

Tags: opengl, x11-forwarding

I am using a remote headles server and with x11 forwarding. I want to forward the display to my local machine. But while running 'glxinfo', I am having the following error:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  24 (X_GLXCreateNewContext)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  66
  Current serial number in output stream:  67
```

On the remote server, I have Linux 18.04 with Nividia GeForce 1080 Ti. The Driver version is 470.57.02 and the Cuda version is 11.4. On my local system, I have Linux 18.04

I also tried the following things:

1. I updated Nvidia drivers and rebooted the system.
2. Changed display manager from gdm to lightdm and ran X server with '+iglx'.

But the error was not resolved. I am also new to Linux. Any help would be appreciated.